# How to get the content of a URL with a hash?

Tags: php, hash, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the content of a url with `file_get_contents()` like this:

`file_get_contents('http://www.website.com');`

Which works fine but I have to also get the contents of a page that looks like this: `http://www.website.com#somevalue` however if I use the same approach as above it just returns the same content as without the hash. Is it possible to get the updated content? I assume they're using backbone or another type of routing to handle this.

Comment: You can't. Hash value is manipulated by javascript in browser.

Comment: #anchors are NOT sent to a server when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like they are generating dynamic content using Javascript. Unfortunately, `file_get_contents` won't be able to execute that JS code -- which explains why you don't get the updated content.

Your best bet to scrape a dynamic page is to use a browser to render the page and scrape the elements. There are a few StackOverflow questions discussing scraping dynamic websites that you should look into.

Comment: I was afraid this could be the case, oh well I'll try to find another approach for this thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### http://www.website.com#somevalue v/s http://www.website.com

Both request the **same page-resource** -> `http://www.website.com`
The navigation further due to the hash, is done using **JavaScript**.

So, there isn't a way you can directly get those contents using **[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)**, as you are fetching the response html, but **not executing** the client-scripts referenced within it.

---

**[J4P5](http://j4p5.sourceforge.net/index.php)** is a JavaScript interpreter written in PHP 5, which might help you execute JS at the server.

Answer (score 0):

URL fragments ("hashes") are not submitted to the server, they're client-side only. If the page changes dynamically on the client-side based on the hash through Javascript, you'll need to download the site, parse it into a DOM, run the embedded Javascript, then scrape the DOM.

In other words, you'll need to emulate a complete browser on your server.
Which is not exactly trivial.

I'd suggest you investigate what is possible in your situation based on the keyword "headless browser".